# How to read available audio tracks in a video file?

Tags: command-line, video, media, metadata

Some video files contain multiple audio tracks. Multiple languages for example. Is there a command line tool which gets information about these audio tracks? Names of the audio tracks would be sufficient.

It should support common formats (mkv, avi,...).

Comment: How could this be done using `avconv` in the `libav-tools` Ubuntu package? Can such a thing be done to identify if audio has surround sound encoded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the top of my head:

```
ffmpeg -i <file> 2>&1 | grep 'Audio:'
```